# Pin Firefox Add-on using Intune policy

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, gpo, intune

Title is essentially what we're looking for. I have already successfully deployed the add-on  itself via a Configuration Profile using Mozilla's documentation for creating a custom ADMX policy.

https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md

What I'd like to do now, is require the add-on to be pinned to the toolbar. At the moment, it is hidden behind the "Puzzle piece" icon.

Is there any way to force this? I do not see any way to modify this under "ExtensionSettings" policy options. Though, I was able to prevent end-user uninstall of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there isn't a way to pin an add-on to the toolbar via an Intune policy as it is considered a user preference and typically managed directly within the Firefox browser by the end user.  You can however use the "[ExtensionInstallForcelist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#extensioninstallforcelist)" policy to forcefully install the add-on.